# How to return user-defined type as varchar2?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types

Let's consider a table with user defined type.

```
create or replace type reftype is object (id number, name varchar2(40), details varchar2(1000));
create table testref(c1 reftype);
insert into testref values (REFTYPE(4, 'asd', 'aaa'));
insert into testref values (REFTYPE(3, 'asf', 'baa'));
insert into testref values (REFTYPE(2, 'asg', 'aba'));
insert into testref values (REFTYPE(1, 'ash', 'aab'));
/
select * from testref;
```

Select returns column with objects of user type. When I execute it in SQL*plus I will see:

```
SQL> select * from testref
REFTYPE(4, 'asd', 'aaa')
REFTYPE(3, 'asf', 'baa')
REFTYPE(2, 'asg', 'aba')
REFTYPE(1, 'ash', 'aab')
```

How can I write my query to return such output as a text (let's say varchar2).

```
SQL> select substr(c1,1,4) from testref;
select substr(c1,1,4) from testref
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got KACPER.REFTYPE
```

The same with:

```
select substr(cast(c1 as varchar2(1000)),1,4) from testref;
```

And I would like to send string representing user defined type to application as a text not as a UDT. Can you advise me how to write a query that will return varchar2 representaion same as I can see in SQL*PLUS?

**EDIT**

My real case is using:

```
create or replace type reftypetab as table of reftype;
```

and query:

```
select cast(collect(c1) as reftypetab) from testref;
```

I would like to have that output either as varchar2: `'KACPER.REFTYPETAB(KACPER.REFTYPE(4,'asd','aaa'),KACPER.REFTYPE(3,'asf','baa'),KACPER.REFTYPE(2,'asg','aba'),KACPER.REFTYPE(1,'ash','aab'))'` or as an XML. But when calling:

```
select xmltype(cast(collect(c1) as reftypetab)) from testref;
```

I got:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XMLTYPE'
```

Do you have any suggestions how can I get XML or text representation of my tabletype?

Comment: What exactly do you want the result to look like? A column for each field in the object?

Comment: @AlexPoole no I'd like to get values like: `'REFTYPE(4, 'asd', 'aaa')'` as a one column. I'd like to get output looking exactly the same as it is in SQL*PLUS now but I need it to be varchar2 not UDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
SELECT T.c1.ID, T.c1.NAME, T.c1.details
FROM TESTREF T;
```

If you like to get all in one (XML string) you can also use

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(c1)
FROM TESTREF;
```

Another way is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE reftype IS OBJECT (ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(40), details VARCHAR2(1000),
    MEMBER FUNCTION TO_VARCHAR2 RETURN VARCHAR2);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY reftype IS 

MEMBER FUNCTION TO_VARCHAR2 RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
    RETURN SELF.ID||','||SELF.NAME||','||SELF.details;
END TO_VARCHAR2;

END;
/


SELECT t.c1.TO_VARCHAR2()
FROM TESTREF t;
```

Comment: XML is something that may help me. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how can I produce on table type build of record type? I've edited question with error I'm getting.

Comment: Does this work: `SELECT XMLELEMENT(reftypetab, XMLAGG(XMLTYPE(c1))) FROM testref;`?

Comment: Yes it works. It is not exactly what I need but it is kind of workaround to obtain it so I'll try to use it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
select t.c1.id||','||t.c1.name||','||t.c1.details text
from testref t;

TEXT
----------------
4,asd,aaa
3,asf,baa
2,asg,aba
1,ash,aab
```

NB For reasons I've never understood, the explicit table alias is mandatory - i.e. the following will **not** work:

```
-- No alias:
select c1.id||','||c1.name||','||c1.details text
from testref;

-- Implicit use of table name as alias:
select testref.c1.id||','||testref.c1.name||','||testref.c1.details text
from testref;
```

Comment: This is just sample type. In real case a have it much more complicated (UDT table of UDT records) so such query is not solution. I'm just looking a method to print or cast UDT without knowing it structure. But thank you for your effort.

Comment: Just curious - why do you have a complicated "UDT table of UDT records" - why not just use simple relational tables to hold data?

Comment: For @Kacper's benefit (I'm sure Tony already knows) [the alias requirement is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7080); it sort of explains it, but not very clearly.

Comment: Explanation is a bit complicated. I'm storing data in relational tables but I need to send data to application that do stream processing. I don't want to send stream with joined data to avoid overload. Now I'm testing if it is better to send multiple streams one for each table and build objects on application side or combine data with nested tables and send one stream that contains flat fields along table types but tools I'm using have no support for processing UDTs. Generally let's say it's some kind of proof of concept ;)

Comment: OK - sounds like a reasonable use case!